# Override admin template with own template

Tags: frontend

How can I override the following admin template in Craft 2?

```
craft/app/templates/users/_edit.html
```

I've tried placing the template in my own template directory, like:

```
templates/users/_edit.html
```

but this doesn't override Craft's own template.

Comment: Did you try templates/admin/users/_edit.html?

Comment: Unfortunately does not work.

Answer (score 4):

For that path, Craft would look for the following template files, and use the first one that exists:

- `craft/app/templates/users/_edit`
- `craft/app/templates/users/_edit.html`
- `craft/app/templates/users/_edit.twig`
- `craft/app/templates/users/_edit/index.html`
- `craft/app/templates/users/_edit/index.twig`
- `craft/plugins/users/templates/_edit`
- `craft/plugins/users/templates/_edit.html`
- `craft/plugins/users/templates/_edit.twig`
- `craft/plugins/users/templates/_edit/index.html`
- `craft/plugins/users/templates/_edit/index.twig`

[[source](https://craftcms.com/classreference/services/TemplatesService#findTemplate-detail)]

As the `users/_edit.html` template in `craft/app/templates` will always exist, it will always find that first and use it.

Comment: This means it's impossible to override core templates?

Comment: yes, as far as I am aware you can't override core templates, there is a `"cp.users.edit"` [template hook](https://craftcms.com/classreference/services/TemplatesService#hook-detail) that might be useful, depending on your specific needs.